# Get Option set label in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm wondering how to get the label for option set field in `CRM 2011` using `LINQ` in early bound.

I have tried to use `FormattedValues["field_name"]` but i got the following error `The given key was not present in the dictionary`.

```
var query = (from username in context.SystemUserSet 
             select new { username.FullName, 
                          Manager = (username.ParentSystemUserId == null) ? string.Empty : username.ParentSystemUserId.Name, 
                          DepartmentValue = username.new_Department, 
                          Department = username.FormattedValues["new_Department"] ,
                          username.SystemUserId });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did lower case fix your issue?

Comment: No, i'm still have the same error message

Comment: Have you checked to see what fields are in the FormattedValues Collection?  I've only used it with Query Expressions, so you can try newing up a new SystemUser, rather than creating a new type, and seeing if you can access the value in that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the option set field in order to be able to access the formatted values:

```
var query = (from username in context.SystemUserSet 
             select new { username.FullName, 
                          username.filed_name
                          Manager = (username.ParentSystemUserId == null) ? string.Empty : username.ParentSystemUserId.Name, 
                          DepartmentValue = username.new_Department, 
                          Department = username.FormattedValues["new_Department"] ,
                          username.SystemUserId
                          })
```

## Update

Didn't see you already selected it (you mis-spelled field).

Always use lowercase.  That's your problem.

```
Department = username.FormattedValues["new_department"]
```

Comment: This is not always true, when creating custom fields you can use mix case in the `SchemaName` and the `SchemaName` is used in programming and it is case sensitive. The `LogicalName` will always be forced to lower case but is not used by the `Entity()` class for attributes. This is why I always require my solutions use all lower case `SchemaName` values, to avoid any potential casing issues.

Comment: @Nicknow, the logical name is always used by the late bound Entities in the Attributes Collection and the FormattedValues collection, so this is why I say to always use lowercase (in C# late bound, oData is different).